# Heroku won't start, Localhost works great

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web-deployment

I can no longer get heroku to work with my app.  It worked for a while, and I don't know what changed it, but I cannot for the life of me get it up and running.  Below is the log file:

```
2016-06-26T17:18:34.982596+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v7 created by evanliewer@gmail.com
2016-06-26T17:18:34.982497+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy da3be34 by evanliewer@gmail.com
2016-06-26T17:18:37.841303+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 35056 -e production`
2016-06-26T17:18:37.981807+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758316+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `block in start'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758294+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:38] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758314+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:177:in `select'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758320+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758318+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:164:in `start'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758320+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758322+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758319+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758324+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758317+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/webrick/server.rb:33:in `start'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758324+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758322+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758323+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758358+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:38] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-06-26T17:18:38.769022+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758325+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758326+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-06-26T17:18:38.758331+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:38] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-06-26T17:18:38.769041+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-06-26T17:18:38.769039+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:47180
2016-06-26T17:18:38.769041+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-06-26T17:18:38.769045+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-06-26T17:18:39.708029+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-06-26T17:18:41.645018+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:41] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=35056
2016-06-26T17:18:41.644736+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:41] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-06-26T17:18:41.644764+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-06-26 17:18:41] INFO  ruby 2.3.0 (2015-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
2016-06-26T17:18:41.896336+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

Comment: could you trying running your app locally with production environment? run `rails server -e production`

Comment: This gave a much clearer error message than heroku did.  Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>  However when I look at my secrets.yml file, it has all 3 requested items

Comment: No those aren't the errors affecting heroku. Update: try to run `rake secret`. This will generate a random secret for you, then run your app with the secret key eg. `SECRET_KEY_BASE=key_from_rake_secret rails s -e production`

Comment: after following that, i get the error An unhandled lowlevel error occurred. The application logs may have details.  and I still have the console saying  2016-06-26 11:52:43 -0700: Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_token` and `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set these values in `config/secrets.yml`>